# Prove $ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^a(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=(-1)^a a! \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a+1)}}{n2^n}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

Nice little generalization:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^a(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=(-1)^a a! \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a+1)}}{n2^n},\quad a=0,1,2,...$$

The point of this post is to save us some calculations in our solutions and here is my proof:

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^a(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx\overset{x\ \mapsto\ 1-x}{=}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^ax\ln(2-x)}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\ln2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^ax}{1-x}\ dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^ax\ln(1-x/2)}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\ln2((-1)^aa!\zeta(a+1))-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n2^n}\int_0^1\frac{x^n\ln^ax}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\ln2((-1)^aa!\zeta(a+1))-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^aa!\left(\zeta(a+1)-H_n^{(a+1)}\right)}{n2^n}\\
&=\ln2((-1)^aa!\zeta(a+1))-\ln2((-1)^aa!\zeta(a+1))+(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a+1)}}{n2^n}\\
&=(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a+1)}}{n2^n}
\end{align}

I came up with such generalization while I was working on some nice harmonic series. Other approaches are appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**: Here is another nice rule

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ax\ln(1+x)}{1-x}dx=(-1)^aa!\left(\ln2\zeta(a+1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(a+1)}}{n}\right)$$

and we can prove it following the same approach above:

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ax\ln(1+x)}{1-x}dx&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_0^1\frac{x^a\ln^nx}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left[(-1)^aa!\left(\zeta(a+1)-H_n^{(4)}\right)\right]\\
&=-(-1)^aa!\left(\zeta(a+1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(a+1)}}{n}\right)\\
&=-(-1)^aa!\left(-\ln2\zeta(a+1)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(a+1)}}{n}\right)\\
&=(-1)^aa!\left(\ln2\zeta(a+1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(a+1)}}{n}\right)
\end{align}

Or

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ax\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}=(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(a+1)}}{n}$$

Comment: This is a very nice generalization! upvoted, recently I've been trying to calculate $\int _0^1\frac{\ln ^4\left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{x}\:dx$, thanks to this it can be related to this kind of harmonic series yet I think it's computation is as complicated as the integral and I wonder how else would you approach this one.

Comment: Thanks @Dennis Orton glad you found it helpful