# Two very advanced harmonic series of weight $5$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request, harmonic-numbers

Very recently Cornel discovered two (*update: in fact there are more as seen from the new entires*)  fascinating results involving harmonic series using ideas from his book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, and which are the core of a new paper he's preparing:

> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^3}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{307}{128}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3}\log ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{8}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{15} \log ^5(2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> -2 \log (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -2 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);
> \end{equation*}
> and
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n-1)^3}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =6 \log (2)-2 \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{12}\log ^4(2)+\frac{1}{12} \log ^5(2)-\frac{3}{2} \zeta (2)-\frac{21}{8} \zeta (3)+\frac{173}{32} \zeta (4)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> +\frac{527}{128} \zeta (5)-\frac{21 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{3}{2} \log (2) \zeta (2)-\frac{7}{2}\log (2)\zeta (3)-4\log (2)\zeta (4)+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2) \zeta (2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> -\frac{1}{2}  \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)+\frac{7}{4}\log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),
> \end{equation*}
> or, after adjustments, the form
> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^3}$$
> $$=\frac{1}{12}\log ^5(2)+\frac{31}{128} \zeta (5)-\frac{1}{2} \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)+\frac{7}{4} \log ^2(2)  \zeta (3)-\frac{17}{8} \log (2)\zeta (4) \\+2\log (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
> **Update I : A new series entry obtained based on the aforementioned series**
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{(2 n)^2}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{23 }{32}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{581}{128} \zeta (5)-\frac{2}{3}\log ^3(2) \zeta (2)+\frac{7}{4} \log^2(2)\zeta (3) +\frac{2}{15} \log ^5(2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> +4\log (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) +4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);
> \end{equation*}
> **Update II : Another new series entry obtained based on the aforementioned series**
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^2}{(2 n)^2}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{23 }{32}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{917 }{128}\zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3}  \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)-\frac{7}{4}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{2}{15} \log ^5(2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> -4 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);
> \end{equation*}
> **Update III : And a new series entry from the same class of series with an unexpected (and outstanding) closed-form**
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2n} H_{n}^{(2)}}{(2 n)^2}=\frac{101 }{64}\zeta (5)-\frac{5 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3);
> \end{equation*}
> It's interesting to note that $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{n} H_{n}^{(2)}}{n^2}=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\zeta(5)$, which may be found calculated in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, by series manipulations.

**A note**: The series from **UPDATE III** seems to be known in literature, and it already appeared here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868355 (see $(3)$).

> **Update IV : Again a new series entry from the same class of series**
> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2 H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^2}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =\frac{9 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{421 }{64}\zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3} \log ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{4} \log ^2(2)\zeta (3) -\frac{2}{15} \log^5(2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> -4 \log(2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);
> \end{equation*}
> **Update V : A strong series - September 26, 2019**
> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2n} H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{4}{3}\log ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{21}{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{713}{64} \zeta (5)-\frac{4}{15} \log ^5(2)$$
> $$-8 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -8\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
> **Update VI : Three very challenging series - September 28, 2019**
> $$i) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{35}{32} \zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{651}{128} \zeta (5)+\frac{1}{3}\log^3(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{7}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta (3)+\frac{53}{16} \log (2)\zeta (4) -\frac{1}{30} \log ^5(2)$$
> $$+4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
> $$ii) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^2}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{35}{32} \zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{465}{128} \zeta (5)+\frac{1}{2}\log^3(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{7}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{11}{16} \log (2)\zeta (4) -\frac{1}{12} \log ^5(2)$$
> $$-2\log(2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
> $$iii) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2 H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{21}{16} \zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{217}{64} \zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3}\log^3(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{7}{4}\log^2(2)\zeta (3)+ \log (2)\zeta (4) -\frac{1}{15} \log ^5(2)$$
> $$+8\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
> **Update VII : Critical series relation used in the Update VI - September 28, 2019**
> $$i) \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^2}{(2 n+1)^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{1}{6}\log ^3(2)\zeta (2) -4\log (2)\zeta (4)+\frac{279}{32} \zeta (5)-\frac{1}{20} \log ^5(2)-2 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right);$$
> $$ii) \ 4 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}^2}{(2 n+1)^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2 H_{2 n}}{(2 n+1)^2}$$
> $$=\frac{49}{16} \zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{1147}{64}\zeta (5)+\frac{4}{3}\log^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{21}{4} \log ^2(2)\zeta (3) -\frac{15}{4}\log (2)\zeta (4)-\frac{4}{15} \log ^5(2)$$
> $$-8 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -8\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
> where $H_n^{(m)}=1+\frac{1}{2^m}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^m}, \ m\ge1,$ designates the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $m$, $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function, and $\operatorname{Li}_n$ denotes the Polylogarithm function.

**A note**: for example, for those interested, one of the possible ways of calculating both series from **UPDATE III** and **UPDATE IV** is based on building a system of relations with the two series by exploiting $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \log^2(1-x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})=\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{1-x}$.
Apart from this, the series from **UPDATE III** allows at least a (very) elegant approach by using different means.

> Using the first series we may obtain (based on the series representation of $\log(1-x)\log(1+x)$ and the integral $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\textrm{d}x$) a way for proving that $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{29 }{64}\zeta (5)-\frac{5 }{8}\zeta (2) \zeta (3).$$
>
> Then, based on the solution below and using the alternating harmonic series in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, we have
> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
> $$=\frac{5 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{123 }{32}\zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3}  \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)-\frac{7}{4}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{2}{15}\log ^5(2)\\-4 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
> And if we add up the two previous integrals, we get
> $$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
> $$=\frac{275}{32}\zeta (5)-\frac{5 }{8}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{4}{3}  \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)-\frac{7}{2}  \log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{4}{15}\log ^5(2)\\-8 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-8 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
> **Update (integrals): Another curious integral arising during the calculations**
> $$\int_0^1 \frac{x \log (x) \log(1-x^2) \operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{41 }{32}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)-\frac{269 }{128}\zeta (5).$$

**QUESTION**: Have these series ever been known in literature? I'm not interested in solutions but only if the series appear anywhere in the literature.

Comment: David Bailey would be as likely to know as anyone.

Comment: Cornel is the real boss.

Comment: Have you tried to contact Bailey, 97357329?

Comment: @GerryMyerson May I guess you refer to David H. Bailey? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_H._Bailey_(mathematician). I didn't yet. I don't know him personally.

Comment: Yes, that's the man. He's very approachable & I think he'd be interested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: the paper mentioned below is the preprint [On the calculation of two essential harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$ by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055_On_the_calculation_of_two_essential_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n)

A solution in large steps by **Cornel Ioan Valean**:

Considering $\displaystyle -\log(1+y)\log(1-y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y^{2n} \frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{y^{2n}}{n^2}$ where we divide both sides by $y$ and then integrate from $y=0$ to $y=x$, we have $\displaystyle -\int_0^x \frac{\log(1+y)\log(1-y)}{y}\textrm{d}y=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{2n} \frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n^2}+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{x^{2n}}{n^3}$. Now, if we multiply both sides of this last result by $\log(1+x)/x$ and then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, using the fact that $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\log(1+x) \textrm{d}x=\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n}$, we get

{*A specific note*: one can multiply both sides of the relation above by $\log(1-x)/x$ instead of $\log(1+x)/x$ and use the integral, $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-H_n/n$, but later in the process one might like to use though the version $\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\log(1+x) \textrm{d}x$ to nicely get the calculations.}

$$\underbrace{-\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\log(1+y)\log(1-y)}{y}\textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle I}=\frac{5}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^4}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nH_{2n}}{n^3}.$$

Integrating by parts, the integral $I$ may be written as $5/16\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(-x) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x}_{J}$, and then we may write that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_nH_{2n}}{n^3}=2\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(-x) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{5}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+\frac{7}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^4}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}\tag1 .$$

Now, the last *magical* part comes from considering expressing the integral $J$ in a different way, and by using the Cauchy product, $\displaystyle \operatorname{Li}_2(-x)\log(1+x)=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n^3}-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n  x^n\frac{H_n}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^n\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}$, we get that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(-x) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x= -\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+3\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_n}{n^4}\\-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}.\tag2$$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ and collecting the values of the series from the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, we are done with the first series.

To get the value of the second series we might use the relation:

> \begin{equation*}
> \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n-1)^3}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{(2 n)^3}
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> =6 \log (2)-2 \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{12}\log ^4(2)+\frac{3}{20} \log ^5(2)-\frac{3}{2} \zeta (2)-\frac{21}{8} \zeta (3)+\frac{173}{32} \zeta (4)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> +\frac{55}{32} \zeta (5)-\frac{5 }{4}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{3}{2} \log (2) \zeta (2)-\frac{7}{2}\log (2)\zeta (3)-4\log (2)\zeta (4)+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(2) \zeta (2)
> \end{equation*}
> \begin{equation*}
> -\frac{5}{6}  \log ^3(2)\zeta (2)+\frac{21}{8}\log ^2(2)\zeta (3)-2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+4 \log (2)\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),
> \end{equation*}

and this is obtained by using a very similar strategy to the one given in Section **6.59**, pages $530$-$532$, from the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. The critical identity here is given in **(6.289)**.

A detailed solution will appear soon in a new paper.

**UPDATE** (September $30$, $2019$)

**A magical way to the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}$ by Cornel Ioan Valean**

By the Cauchy product, we have $\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2) \log(1-x^2)= 3\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{x^{2 n}}{n^3}-2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } x^{2n}\frac{H_n}{n^2}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } x^{2n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}$, and if we multiply both sides by $\log(1-x)/x$, and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, using that $\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log(1-x)\textrm{d}x=-H_n/n$, and doing all the reductions, we arrive at

$$2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n} H_n^{(2)}}{(2 n)^2}-12\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^4}+12\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n^4}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^3}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log \left(1-x^2\right) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+2 \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(-x) \log ^2(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x\\+2 \int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2(1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{Li}_2\left(x^2\right) \log (1+x) \log (1-x)}{x} \textrm{d}x+2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_n^2}{n^3}+2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}\\-2 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_n^{(2)}}{n^3},$$
where the last integral is given here [Two very advanced harmonic series of weight $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345073/two-very-advanced-harmonic-series-of-weight-5/3345138#3345138), and all the last resulting harmonic series are given in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. The reduction to the last series has been achieved by using the identity, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log^2(1-x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$. The series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n H_{2 n}}{n^3}$ maybe found calculated in the paper [On the calculation of two essential harmonicseries with a weight 5 structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type H_{2n} by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335920055_On_the_calculation_of_two_essential_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n).
Thus, we have

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}=\frac{101}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac5{16}\zeta(2)\zeta(3).$$

All the details will appear in a new paper.

**UPDATE** (October $30$, $2019$)
The details with respect to the evaluation of the previous series may be found in the preprint [The evaluation of a special harmonic series with a weight $5$ structure, involving harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336148969_The_evaluation_of_a_special_harmonic_series_with_a_weight_5_structure_involving_harmonic_numbers_of_the_type_H_2n?fbclid=IwAR0l5IHWlch50VYofVcdRYijjvGw0btgGcKqcCaSe3iVlwAbQjmNjU_E49Y)

**UPDATE** (July $05$, $2020$)
The two essential series stated above may be found now as an article [here](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jca-16-01.pdf).

**A very simple solution to one of the key logarithmic integrals stated above, $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n}$**

*Solution (by Cornel):*
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n-1}\ln(1+x)\textrm{d}x= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)' \log(1+x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2n}\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^{2n}}{1+x}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{2n}\sum _{k=1}^{2 n} (-1)^{k-1} \int_0^1 x^{k-1} \textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2n}\sum _{k=1}^{2 n}\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{2n}.
\end{equation*}

**BONUS: A very simple solution to a logarithmic integral strongly related to the key integral above, $ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\ln(1+x)\textrm{d}x=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{2n+1}$**

*Solution (by Cornel):*
\begin{equation*}
 \int_{0}^1 x^{2n}\ln(1+x)\textrm{d}x= \int_{0}^1 \left(\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)' \ln(1+x)\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\int_0^1\frac{1+x^{2n+1}}{1+x}\textrm{d}x=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (-1)^{k-1}\int_0^1x^{k-1}\textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}=\frac{2\log(2)}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{H_n-H_{2n}}{2n+1}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: (+1) for sharing such awesome stuff.

Comment: @AliShather Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

We have

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-y)}{1-y}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)})\tag{1}$$

integrate both sides of (1) from $y=0$ to $y=x$ to get

$$-\frac13\ln^3(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n}}{n}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\tag{2}$$

Now replace $x$ with $x^2$ in (2) then multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$, also note that $\int_0^1 -x^{2n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_{2n}}{2n}$ we get

$$\frac13\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x^2)\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large I}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{2n^2}\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$

Rearranging the terms to get

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^2}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n^{(2)}}{(2n)^2}+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}H_n}{(2n)^3}-8\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}+\frac16I\tag{3}$$

@nospoon mentioned in  equation (3) of [his solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868355) that he found

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}\,H_{2n}}{n^2} =\frac{11}{4}\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)-\frac{47}{16}\zeta(5)$$

Or

$$\boxed{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2n} H_{n}^{(2)}}{(2 n)^2}=\frac{101 }{64}\zeta (5)-\frac{5 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)}$$

Also Cornel elegantly calculated the second sum above

$$\boxed{\small{\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}H_n }{(2 n)^3}=\frac{307}{128}\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{1}{3}\ln ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{8}  \ln ^2(2)\zeta (3)-\frac{1}{15} \ln ^5(2)
-2 \ln (2) \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -2 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}}$$

For the third sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}+\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}$$

plugging the common results:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{n}}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$$

we get

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=\frac{37}{64}\zeta(5)-\frac14\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$$

For the remaining integral $I$, we use the magical identity

$$(a+b)^3a=a^4-b^4+\frac12(a+b)^4-\frac12(a-b)^4-(a-b)^3b$$

with $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ we can write

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx}_{x^2\mapsto x}\\-\underbrace{\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln(1+x)}{x}\ dx}_{\frac{1-x}{1+x}\mapsto x}$$

$$I=\frac54\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{4!\zeta(5)}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}\ dx}_{K}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac{93}{4}\zeta(5)}+\underbrace{2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{J}$$

$$I=\frac{27}{4}\zeta(5)-K+J\tag{4}$$

we have

\begin{align}
K&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1+x)}{x}=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^4x}{x}\ dx+\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx\\
&=\frac15\ln^52+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{1/2}^1 x^{n-1}\ln^4x\ dx\\
&=\frac15\ln^52+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{24}{n^5}-\frac{24}{n^52^n}-\frac{24\ln2}{n^42^n}-\frac{12\ln^22}{n^32^n}-\frac{4\ln^32}{n^22^n}-\frac{\ln^42}{n2^n}\right)\\
&=4\ln^32\zeta(2)-\frac{21}2\ln^22\zeta(3)+24\zeta(5)-\frac45\ln^52-24\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)
\end{align}

and

$$J=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x^2}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\ dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1+x}\ dx$$

using [the rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293274)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln^ax\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{2}\right)}{1-x}\ dx=(-1)^aa!\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{a+1}}{n}$$

allows us to write

\begin{align}
J&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\ dx-\ln2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x}\ dx\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n H_n\int_0^1x^n\ln^3x\ dx-\ln2\left(-\frac{21}4\zeta(4)\right)\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}+6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{(n+1)^4}+\frac{21}{4}\ln2 \zeta(4)\\
&=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^4}-\frac{45}{8}\zeta(5)+\frac{21}{4}\ln2 \zeta(4)
\end{align}

Plugging

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}=\frac78\ln2\zeta(4)+\frac38\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\zeta(5)$$

we get

$$J=\frac{279}{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Plugging the results of $K$ and $J$ in (4) we get

$$\boxed{\small{I=24\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+24\ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac3{16}\zeta(5)-\frac{21}{4}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{21}2\ln^22\zeta(3)-4\ln^32\zeta(2)+\frac45\ln^52}}$$

and finally by substituting the boxed results in (3) we get

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{2 n}H_n^2 }{(2 n)^2}
> =\frac{9 }{16}\zeta (2) \zeta (3)+\frac{421 }{64}\zeta (5)+\frac{2}{3} \ln ^3(2)\zeta (2) -\frac{7}{4} \ln ^2(2)\zeta (3)\\ -\frac{2}{15} \ln^5(2)
> -4 \ln2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) -4 \operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

---

**Note:**

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973408) and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n^{(4)}}{n}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236084).

Comment: Thank you and sorry I didnt read that part.